# What is the need for Logical Memory?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

When I study OS,I find a concept Logical Memory.So Why there is a need for a Logical Memory?How does a CPU generate Logical Memory?The output of "**&ptr**" operator is Logical or physical Address?Is Logical Memory and Virtual Memory same?

Comment: I suggest reading e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_address amd http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory.

Comment: The return value of `sizeof` is a *size*, not an address of any sort.

Comment: Sry The output of &ptr is physical or logical address?

Comment: do some reading and do some search you will find your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about C's and C++'s `sizeof`, it returns a size and never an address. And the CPU does not generate any memory.

On **x86** CPUs there are several layers in address calculations and translations. x86 programs operate with **logical addresses** comprised of two items: a **segment selector** (this one isn't always specified explicitly in instructions and may come from the `cs`, `ds`, `ss` or `es` segment register) and an **offset**.

The **segment selector** is then translated into the **segment base address** (either directly (multiplied by 16 in the real address mode and in the virtual 8086 mode of the CPU) or by using a special **segment descriptor table** (global or local, GDT or LDT, in the protected mode of the CPU), the selector is used as an index into the descriptor table, from where the base address is pulled).

Then the sum **segment base address** + **offset** forms a **linear address** (AKA **virtual address**).

If the CPU is in the real address mode, that's the final, **physical address**.

If the CPU is in the protected mode (or virtual 8086), that **linear/virtual address** can be further translated into the **physical address** by means of **page tables** (if page translation is enabled, of course, otherwise, it's the final physical address as well).

**Physical memory** is your RAM or ROM (or flash). **Virtual memory** is **physical memory** extended by the space of disk storage (could be flash as well as we now have SSDs).

You really need to read up on this. You seem to have no idea.

Comment: Sry The output of &ptr is physical or logical address?

Comment: Logical. And it's not necessarily logical from the CPU's point of view. It may coincide with virtual or physical, depending on the compiler and the platform.